# Aplicação Móvel efetuando chamadas em Delphi

Tags: delphi, mobile

Queria saber se é possível realizar chamadas com um aplicativo mobile construído em delphi ?

Se for possível mostrar um exemplo de como implementar.

Answer (score 0):

Sim aplicações construídas em delphi nos permitem acessar api's como `PhoneDialer` para efetuar chamadas por exemplo. Mas existem inúmeros outras bibliotecas que nos permitem realizar outras operações com o dispositivo.

Um exemplo bem simples de como implementar esse recurso em um aplicativo ficaria da seguinte maneira:

**Antes de iniciarmos a implementação do código que ira efetuar a chamada, devemos adicionar a cláusula uses dos seguintes Namespaces:** `FMX.PhoneDialer, FMX.Platform.`

Agora basta implementar o seguinte código, o qual é muito simples de ser construído.

```
var 
 chamada: IFMXPhoneDialerService;
begin

   TPlatformServices.Current.SuportsPlatformService(IFMXPhoneDialerService, IInterface(chamada));



  if Assigned(chamada) then
     chamada.Call('numero a ser chamado');



end;
```